# Can child templates stored in a base class array, use an overloaded virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

In hope to simplify a homework problem dealing with inheritance, I thought it might be better to use polymorphism to accomplish the task.  It isn't required, but makes much more sense if possible.  I am, however, getting symbol errors making it work as I thought it should or just the base class definition is called.  I want the overloaded function based on the object to be called.

```
template <class T>
class Fruit {
  private:
    int count;
    T type;
  public:
    virtual void Info();
};

template <class T>
class Apple : public Fruit<T> {
  private:
    int variety;
  public:
    void Info();
};

// more fruit-child classes

vector<Fruit<int> > fruits; // contains object of various derived types

...

for(int i=0; i<fruits.size(); i++
    fruits[i].Info();
```

Comment: What is the purpose of type? If it's a type field, you probably don't need it at all.

Comment: Your vector of Fruit should be a vector of `Fruit *`, otherwise you'll get slicing problems.

Comment: What the problem you are trying to solve? What is the motivation of throwing in *both* compile-time polymorphism (templates) *as well as* run-time polymorphism (inheritance)?

Comment: I agree, the purpose of type is unnecessary.  That is, however, the assignment.  It is just to illustrate use of a datatype in a template.  But doing so, makes the data-structure a mess.  Being able to accomplish the above problem would make that better.

Comment: @ArunSaha the motivation for templates is the assignment.  But the way data must be structured leaves a large number of arrays to store all the data in the program.  I'd rather just have a few.  Even better, if I could have an array of Fruit<T> which accepted Apple<int> and Apple<double> objects, that would be ideal.... provided I can overload that Info() function.

Comment: @JoshD using `vector<Fruit<int> *> fruits;` gets compile errors when trying to do a push_back of an object.  I thought all vectors were copies, so being a pointer doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @mike_b: the pointer comes into play when you want to put an `Apple` in there also. If you have a vector of `Fruit`, and you add an `Apple`, it will cut off all the apple parts (`variety` in your case). Read the linked article from my answer about slicing.

Comment: @mike_b: alternatively, you could use a vector of references. How are you creating your new `Friut`s

Comment: @JoshD `type` is arbitrary and is overloaded data.  It is really just part of the assignment to place `type` where and how it is.  For example, `T` being `char[25]`, `type` could be initalized as (ignoring private) `appleObj.type = "organic";`

Comment: @JoshD I currently am just testing with dynamic creation.  `Apple<int> a; fruits.push_back(a);`

Comment: @mike_b: OK. That will cause problems with the pointers. This starts to get into some more complicated and dangerous things. A shared_ptr would be better, but that's also something you'd need to learn about. You'll need to make your fruit on the heap with `new`. Then you'll have to `delete` them when you're done. You may be getting in over your head... If you're up for it, Google heterogeneous containers.

Comment: nope, I'm familiar with using new / delete.  Let me rewrite it.

Comment: @mike_b: well, I hope this has been helpful for you. Good luck with your assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to leave the type thing aside, though I think you probably don't need it and therefore don't need the template... but, here's what you need:

First, the vector should be of pointers:

`vector<Fruit<int> *> fruits;`

this prevents [slicing](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~hoover/Courses/201/201-New-Notes/lectures/section/slice.htm) (where the Apple part of the object is cut off).

Also, now that you have pointers, your loop will change:

```
for(int i=0; i<fruits.size(); i++)
    fruits[i]->Info();
```

This will now call the appropriate `Info` function for the type of fruit you have.

Comment: I would use vector< shared_ptr< Fruit< int > > > instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @VJo: That would be best, but I'm assuming for this assignment that won't be allowed. Also, given the OP's question, I'm assuming that OP would benefit from learning this method.

Comment: This gives compile issues `vector<Fruit<int> *> fruits; Apple<int> a; fruits.push_back(a);`  Thanks for the help so far, this is definitely in the direction I need...

Comment: @mike_b: Since the vector is of pointers, you'll need to push the address of the apple: `fruits.push_back(&a);`. But since you created the apple on the stack, it'll be destroyed before you want it to be. That's why you need to create it on the heap with `new`: `Apple<int> *a = new Apple<int>;` Then you push the pointer a: `fruits.push_back(a);`

Comment: Without leaving things allocated, can I say create a pointer `Apple<int> *a` and then as needed, create new heap allocations such as `for(int i=0;i<10;i++){a=new Apple<int>; fruits.push_back(a);}`?  Then to cleanup, I would need to do say `Apple<int> *temp; temp=fruits.back(); fruits.pop_back(); delete temp;` to de-allocate the memory from the heap?

Comment: @mike_b: YES! That's exactly right, and works wonderfully. Well done. If you wanna get crazy, you can cut it down to `fruits.push_back(new Apple<int>)` Cleanup is just fine how it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I just need to adapt this, but it definitely works now as I hoped.